# Why is this Jquery / JavasScript so slow?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc

I have this script, and there is a very noticeable 1-2 second delay to change the border color around a textbox (has-success) or (has-error). Basically I want to change the color (Green or Red) and show/hide a glyphicon based on an if/else statement.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#lookupExtGuest").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/NewUserRequest/LookupData",
            data: { userInput: document.getElementById("ExtGuestID").value },
            success: function (result) {
                if (result.indexOf("was found") != -1) {
                    var d = document.getElementById("extGuestlookup")
                    d.className = d.className + " has-success"
                    $('#extGuestGlyphiconOK').show();
                    $('#extGuestGlyphiconRemove').hide();
                }
                else {
                    var d = document.getElementById("extGuestlookup")
                    d.className = d.className + " has-error"
                    $('#extGuestGlyphiconOK').hide();
                    $('#extGuestGlyphiconRemove').show();
                }
            }

        });
    });
});
```

Here is the reponse times from the chrome Network menu:

[image]

Comment: What is the actual bottleneck?  If it takes a moment for the server to respond with data then this code has nothing to do with that.  Round trips to web servers are not instantaneous things.

Comment: What is `result.length`? Is it hundreds of MBs? Unless that's the case, there's no way this code takes more than a few ms.

Comment: The time you notice is actually the time for the server side script takes to answer. If you need to measure it, use the F12 console, around "Networking" (may vary depending of the browser).

Comment: As @David mentioned, the wait time is the return trip to and from the server. If you are worried about the user experience, you could add a spinner gif to indicate to the user that the information is being gathered

Comment: @Zeratops I have added a picture of the Network menu from chrome. This is the response time when I click the button. I have messed around with it a few times and the response time varies grately, sometimes its much longer. Also there seems to be some weird errors? Like i said im very new to this and I dont know if those errors are part of the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The javascript in the `success` function should only take a few milliseconds to run provided the `result` string is only a few kilobytes.  A good way to test something like this is with [console.time()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/time):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#lookupExtGuest").click(function () {
        console.time('lookupDataRequestTimer');

        $.ajax({
            url: "/NewUserRequest/LookupData",
            data: { userInput: document.getElementById("ExtGuestID").value },
            success: function (result) {
                console.timeEnd('lookupDataRequestTimer');

                console.time('lookupDataCallbackTimer');

                if (result.indexOf("was found") != -1) {
                    var d = document.getElementById("extGuestlookup")
                    d.className = d.className + " has-success"
                    $('#extGuestGlyphiconOK').show();
                    $('#extGuestGlyphiconRemove').hide();
                }
                else {
                    var d = document.getElementById("extGuestlookup")
                    d.className = d.className + " has-error"
                    $('#extGuestGlyphiconOK').hide();
                    $('#extGuestGlyphiconRemove').show();
                }

                console.timeEnd('lookupDataCallbackTimer');
            }

        });
    });
});
</script>
```

I've added some `console.time` functions into the code you posted. If you run this you should see the timing in the web-inspector's console. This way you can see whether the ajax call (`lookupDataRequestTimer`) or the success callback (`lookupDataCallbackTimer`) is slower and by how much.

If the ajax call is much slower and the file being requested isn't too large (which I suspect) you'll probably find the server is quite slow. To speed things up you could run the `GET` request on page load and cache the data into a variable and access it immediately on click.

Edit: I see you've just added the network screenshot. The request's size is very small, 590b, but it's taking 2.47s. This is definitely the server which is taking a while to respond. Can you take another picture of the entire network tab, including the times for the html page itself.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use `('#parent children').remove()` and then `('#parent').append('<element><\element>')` for each node.

Or, to hide `slow`:

`hide('slow')` or `show('slow')`